# Azure Provisioning state fails for VMSS with custom image & elb

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm-templates

I am getting below error for VMSS with custom image & elb

My template link: https://github.com/linuxgambler/azure/blob/master/vmss_elb.json

> Error: 
>            "error": {
>            "details": [
>                      {
>                      "code": "NotFound",
>                      "message": "Resource /subscriptions/6793721a-ea46-406d-ac42-d4488d1a5c0d/resourceGroups/EMC-US-WEST/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/AZURE-TESLB
>   not found."
>                    }
>                 ],
>                "code": "InvalidResourceReference",
>               "message": "Resource /subscriptions/6793721a-ea46-406d-ac42-d4488d1a5c0d/resourceGroups/EMC-US-WEST/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/AZURE-TESLB
>   referenced by resource
>   /subscriptions/6793721a-ea46-406d-ac42-d4488d1a5c0d/resourceGroups/EMC-US-West/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/azure-tes was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists,
>   and that both resources are in the same region."
>             }
>        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `dependsOn` property to VMSS definition.

```
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
"name": "[variables('vmssName')]",
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
"apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
"dependsOn": [
    "[variables('lbID')]"
],
"sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('vmSku')]",
    "tier": "Standard",
    "capacity": "[parameters('instanceCount')]"
},
```

Right now its getting created before the load balancer, that's why its erroring out.

Comment: I have added the parameter but now getting below validation error:  Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/emc-west-' cannot reference itself. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Comment: i forgot to fix the typo, you obviously need to depend on the ilb, not on itself @SagarMalve